# Importing S3 generics from another package

Tags: r

I am writing a package which builds on the `autoplot()` generic from the ggplot2 package. Currently, I have a function named `breg()` which acts as a constructor for the class `breg`; the output of which can be plotted using `autoplot.breg()`. Within my `breg()` function, my Roxygen commands are as such:

```
#' @export breg
```

Then within `autoplot.breg()` I have

```
#' @import ggplot2
#' @importFrom ggplot2 autoplot
#'
#' @method autoplot breg
#' @export
```

I wasn't convinced I needed `@importFrom ggplot2 autoplot` if I was importing the whole of `ggplot2`. However I digress, in my `NAMESPACE` file I have

```
S3method(autoplot,breg)
export(breg)
import(ggplot2)
importFrom(ggplot2,autoplot)
```

My question is, why do I still have the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In setup_ns_exports(pkg, export_all) :
  Objects listed as exports, but not present in namespace: autoplot
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you are generating your `NAMESPACE` file from the Roxygen doc comments, right?

Comment: Yes I am. I have just removed the `@importFrom ggplot2 autoplot` and it seems to have removed the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note the following from Hadley’s [*R packages*](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html):

“Older versions of roxygen required explicit `@method generic class` tags for all S3 methods. From version 3.0.0 onward, this is no longer needed as roxygen2 will figure it out automatically.” Using `@importFrom` is, as far as I can tell, completely deprecated.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think originally I had `@export autoplot` for some reason which led me to believe an error I was seeing meant I needed the `@importFrom ggplot2 autoplot` function. Regarding `@method generic class`, I only have it as Roxygen isn't recognizing some of my methods, for example `breg.data.frame()` is a function which is exported, but not as an S3method. I currently have v4.1.0 installed.

Comment: Yes, functions with unconventional class names (such as `data.frame`, which contain a dot, may require explicit `@export generic class` declarations because it’s otherwise ambiguous which you mean: `@export breg data.frame` or `@export breg.data frame`. Sucks.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Hadley goes to great length to talk about this in his book which I found really interesting. It's why I (and probably most people) tend to use underscores instead of points for naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@importFrom package generic` declarations aren't needed if you already have `@import package`.

Checking the `@export` field is essential to avoiding errors!

In addition, functions with unconventional class names (such as data.frame), which contain a dot, may require explicit `@export generic class` declarations because it’s otherwise ambiguous which you mean: `@export breg data.frame` or `@export breg.data frame`.